# Module compiled with Swift 5.1.3 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.5.2 in Flutter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, dart

i m trying to build a flutter app in ios

and i have encounted this problem

***Module compiled with Swift 5.1.3
cannot be imported by the Swift 5.5.2 compiler:***

i have seen some solutions like

**adding YES to Build libraries for distribution**

but this solution works only in native IOS it is not available in frameworks like flutter

Comment: This can happen when a flutter plugin contains a pre-compiled framework - The framework will need to be recompiled, which would need to be done by the owner of the plugin, if the source code for the module is not included. If you can find out which package contains the problematic module, check to see if an updated version is available for that package

Comment: the problem here is the project is big and already exists in android, there are more than 30 packages on it, is there a way to find the package that is causing the problem without checking on all of them

Comment: You might be able to find the problematic module if you open the ios project in xcode, build it, and then check the xcode error log when the build fails - Sometimes you can find more details about an error that way than what shows up in the terminal for a flutter build